# Por que meus votos contras foram cancelados e de outros usuários não?

Tags: debate, suporte, voto-contra, sinalização, votos

Ontem notei 4 respostas idênticas que não respondiam especificamente as perguntas, olhando o conteúdo das respostas todas além de idênticas pareciam tentar promover o site do autor, hoje fui notificado que os votos foram cancelados:

> [image: voto contra]

Além de votar contra eu sinalizei todas respostas, pelos motivos que já citei:

- Não respondiam exatamente as perguntas
- eram todas respostas idênticas
- o autor parecia estar usando o campo de respostas para promover um site pessoal relacionado ao assunto

Notem que todas minhas sinalizações foram marcadas como úteis:

> [image: sinalizações]

tá bom, eu sei que sinalizações marcadas como `útil` são uma mera identificação e não significa que alguma ação tenha sido tomada a partir disto.

Mas o que me deixou intrigado foi que os downvotes de outros usuários não foram revertidos, presumo então uma destas possibilidades:

- Fui o único a negativar todas respostas do autor, ou seja isto foi uma reversão
- Foi uma reversão manual por algum motivo válido
- O sistema identificou minhas sinalizações e de alguma forma assumiu que eu poderia estar usando de forma exagerada as ferramentas

Gostaria de saber exatamente o porque aparentemente somente os meus votos foram revertidos.

Comment: Acho que é porque como a resposta foi marcada como spam, o pontinho que você pagou como custo por votar negativo foi te devolvido porque não faz sentido "cobrar taxa" para quem marca spam. Mas como só acho, e não tenho certeza, deixo isso como comentário ao invés de resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não fui o unico que negativou a marcar como SPAM, portanto não faz muito sentido, a não ser que seja o que eu disse, eu **supostamente** abusei do uso da ferramenta

Comment: Como você sabe que downvotes de outros usuários não foram revertidos?

Comment: @Math é simples, eu entrei nas perguntas eu antes aparecia o amarelo no botão downvote, indicando o meu downvote, mas agora não aparece, ou seja é como se eu não tivesse votado ... no entanto as perguntas continuam com -4 ~ -5, que se tivessem sido revertidos provavelmente a pergunta estaria com 0 votos. Eu não estou dizendo que sou o unico que recebi a reversão, mas que é provavel que eu recebi (e talvez mais alguém) mas outros não receberam... a não ser que eu tenha entendido mal o sistema

Comment: Bom, com certeza todo mundo recebeu +1 de volta, sobre as setinhas laranjas indicando que você votou na reposta já não sei dizer como que aparece para cada usuário, mas vou te dizer que achei o comportamento bem estranho, por exemplo [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281607/3117) ele inicialmente mostra -5, quando eu clico para expandir os votos ele mostra 0/-3, depois disso não mostra -5 nunca mais, apenas -3. Veja essa [imagem ilustrativa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAIe1.gif) do que aconteceu aqui comigo.

Comment: @Math então, sim receberam, mas a mensagem é diferente e eu entrei em uma por uma das perguntas... sim, essa do -5 eu notei também, por isto achei estranho. Vou aguardar.

Comment: Será porque não foram feitas em sequência em pouco intervalo de tempo? Acho que o sistema identifica como serial votes?

Comment: @dvd foi o que eu mencionei na pergunta *O sistema identificou minhas sinalizações e de alguma forma assumiu que eu poderia estar usando de forma exagerada as ferramentas*, por isto estou esperando um feedback de um moderador, se bem que conversei com o Math e ele disse que não houve nada nas ferramentas de moderadores, o jeito é esperar algum feedback.

Comment: humm.. Acho que foi ontem, algum abençoado entrou numa pergunta e negativou a minha resposta e a de outro parceiro, poucos minutos depois o sistema reverteu rs... I love this system! :)

Comment: @dvd ou então a pessoa reconheceu que a sua resposta era boa e por decisão própria ele removeu o voto.

Comment: Não. Os dois votos foram revertidos, o meu e o do outro parça.

Comment: @dvd então apareceu no seu profile, na aba de votos, que foi realmente reversão?

Comment: Apareceu... aí entrei lá na pergunta e vi que o do parça tb foi revertido.

Comment: Eu mesmo já votei negativo em varias respostas numa mesma pergunta porque eram todas sinistras... pouco tempo depois voltou tudo rs

Answer (score 3):

O sistema invalidou os votos automaticamente.

O que fizeste, ainda que não houvesse propriamente um problema neste caso, é normalmente um comportamento que tentamos desencorajar: ver um mau post dum autor, e ir ver os outros todos, e largar downvotes em todos — aos "olhos" do sistema, estás a votar no utilizador, e não nos posts.

Comment: Outro moderador me informou que não havia sinais disto e ele mesmo achou estranho o comportamento.

Comment: Pois, mas... 4 votos no mesmo minuto: não costuma ser considerado um comportamento normal, não :)

Comment: Então .... como eu já citei, foi uma reversão, mas como o outro moderador me disse que não tinha sinais disto fiquei intrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento os moderadores podem ter a impressão de que nada errado aconteceu, mas o algoritmo que detecta votos seriais tem outra impressão diferente. Esse algoritmo não se reporta a ninguém e tem mais autoridade que os moderadores (i.e.: a reversão não pode ser desfeita).

Comment: @Renan estou repetindo o que um moderador me disse, eu não estou afirmando nada e nem confirmando nada, baseado no entendimento da experiencia do moderador que citei antes ele me disse que estava estranho e não tinha certeza do que ocorreu. A conversa rolou no chat.